# Extract a substring from a string in a powershell

Tags: string, powershell

I have to write a  powershell script to read data from an input file.There are many data that needs to be extracted from the input text file, one of such data is
Time In State : 3d 10:20
From the above data how can i extract only 3d 10:20 and assign to a variable?

I tried with the following below mentioned command-

```
$a= Time In State : 3d 10:20
$b=("$a" -split ':')[1].substring(1,5)
```

but iam not getting the expected output.
please provide me with proper syntax

Thanks

Comment: You don't bother explaining what the unexpected output is and how it differs from desired. Hint: you got more than one colon, so check what `("$a" -split ':')` returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way:

```
$a = "Time In State : 3d 10:20"
$a -replace '^.+:\s'
```

Following your code ( but avoid this please):

```
( -join ( $a -split '(:)')[2..4]).trim()
```

Comment: @user3568228 if it's working, please mark his answer as accepted. It lets future users with similar issues know that the question was solved, adds some finality to the question (so others don't keep coming to try and give an acceptable answer), and gives him credit towards his reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
'Time In State : 3d 10:20 ' -split '^.+?:'

 3d 10:20
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also assign any matches to a different variable using the -match and a regular expression to catch anything formatted similarly. If it matches the regular expression you can call the $matches[0] magic variable to get that substring:

```
$a = 'Time In State : 3d 10:20'
$b = $a -match '[0-9]{1,2}d\s[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}'
if($b)
{
    $matches[0]
}
else
{
    'No Match'
}

3d 10:20
```